# Questions Show a Mutated Logo in Chat

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

When a question is posted in chat, it shows an icon for the parent network site in the top right corner.  Since the new design and icon for gaming were published, ours appears to have been hit by several trucks or something.

[image: Mutant Arqade Logo in chat]

---

**EDIT:** is it just me, or does it look different now?

[image: The Icon as it looked before, and as it looks now.]

In *this* image, the only problem is that it blends into the background, whereas before it looked dark where it shouldn't have.

Comment: This happened with the old logo as well, at least for me. The top of the heart was always cut off just the tiniest bit in the questions feed.

Comment: Nana, nana, nana, nana... BATMAN!

Comment: You can't see the white-on-white part? Shocking!

Comment: @balpha look at the fuselage of the ship in that icon - it's all black when the normal site icon is clearly lightly coloured there, except for the text.

Comment: What you're seeing is a scaled-down version of http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/apple-touch-icon.png, as opposed to http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/favicon.ico.

Comment: @balpha Why does it look different *now*?  When I first asked this, it definitely didn't look like a scaled down version of the apple touch icon, but now it does.

Comment: It did, actually. What your screenshot shows is the apple touch icon scaled down with a simple nearest neighbor algorithm (open it in the Gimp, Image -> Resize, choose 20x20 pixels and interpolation "none" -- modulo minor pixel differences, it'll look just like in your screenshot). Why did your browser not use an interpolated scaling algortihm back then? I don't know. Did you have your screen set to a lower color fidelity? Browser bug? No idea.

Comment: It looks 'fine' now.  Weird.  Well, regardless, it's still white on white, and not very visible.